# How to get caption from Telegramm message(Pyrogram)

Tags: python, parsing, telegram, pyrogram

I'm newbie at Python. I want to parse certain dialog(contains only captions to pics) with Pyrogram. But if i use iter_history() methog it returns none if message contains pic+text.Like that.

```
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client

app = Client("my_acc")
target = "dialog_example"  # "me" refers to your own chat (Saved Messages)

with app:
    for message in app.iter_history(target):
        print(message.text)
```

> None
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.text` is a message's text. If you want the caption of a message (or document rather), access `message.caption`.